# In Rails, how can a mass-assignment be made to an existing model object without warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In a Rails application it's possible to assign some values from `params` to an existing model object, like this:

```
model.attributes = params
```

This would obviously return a `ForbiddenAttributesError` but that can be avoided like this:

```
model.attributes = params.permit(:a, :b, :c)
```

However, although that works, it still outputs a message to the console if `params` contains keys that are not mentioned in the call to `permit`:

```
Unpermitted parameters: d, e, f
```

The warning is pointless because it's already known that `params` contains additional keys and `permit` is being used to select the required subset. It can be avoided by doing

```
model.attributes = params.slice(:a, :b, :c).permit!
```

Is there a more appropriate way to do this assignment that does not require having to `slice` the hash first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The warning is pointless because it's already known that params contains additional keys and permit is being used to select the required subset.

You mistake the purpose of this warning. It is very valuable when you debug why your form doesn't update this new field you added just today. With the warning, looking at the server log you can quickly find out that you forgot to update strong_params filtering.

Also, the warning will only be shown in dev/test environments. It won't appear in production.

But suppose you really hate that warning. In which case you can do this in your app config:

```
# possible values: :raise, :log 
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = false
```

BTW, your code is a bit unorthodox. The common way is to keep the filtering code in one method and call it from both create/update (and whereever else you need it)

```
def update
  @product = ...

  if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:a, :b, :c)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; regarding the last part - I am not doing this in a normal controller scenario. If I was doing so, I would do exactly as you show in your answer.